# How to filter not nullable lines on spark/DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter data and get only the lines which different to null.

I tried the following code :

```
 df_alerte.filter(df_alerte.col("heureEntre").isNotNull().and(df_alerte.col("heureSortie")).isNotNull()).show(1000);
```

That throws :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot 
resolve '((`heureEntre` IS NOT NULL) AND `heureSortie`)' due to data type 
mismatch: differing types in '((`heureEntre` IS NOT NULL) AND `heureSortie`)' 
(boolean and string).;;
'Filter isnotnull((isnotnull(heureEntre#58) && heureSortie#59))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, the following code gives the result I wanted.
it filters the data and returns that the values ​​not null.

```
 df_alerte.filter(col("heureEntre").isNotNull().and(col("heureSortie").isNotNull()))
```

I hope it will help someone